# arrow control for Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

i'm having a problem with Galleria.
the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keypress(function(e)
      {
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
          case 37: //press left arrow  
                $.galleria.prev();
                break;
          case 39: //press right arrow
                $.galleria.next();
                break;  
        }
      });


</script>
```

won't work, it says:
`$.galleria is undefined` 
if i use instead `Galleria.prev()` and `Galleria.next()`
then it says: `Galleria.next is not a function`, and the same fo prev.

i hope somebody with more experience can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: Can you use Galleria without this and go a hello world on your page to test that you have everything set right?

Comment: Is this script appearing in the page before the galleria plugin is included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

galleria seems to have an attachKeyboard method, but i can't get that to work. but playing around with the code you have above, i managed to get arrow controls. try this:

```
<script>
//start galleria
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria.classic.js');
$('#galleria').galleria();

//obtain galleria instance - this might be the step you are missing
var gallery = Galleria.get(0);

//essentially what you had above
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    switch(KeyID) {
        case 37: //press left arrow 
            gallery.prev();
            break;
        case 39: //press right arrow
            gallery.next();
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 ... found this answer while trying to understand why people kept suggesting `$.galleria.next()` would work, and it didn't for me...this *did* work.  Anyone know what the difference in context is?